# Conversion from string to const char* + size_t in ""operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading about the **""operator** and found some weird looking code snip, I did not understand.

I did not understand the conervsion from string "110011" to const char *s, size_t l ?

I was expecting something like:

`int operator "" _b (const std::string) { .. }` or 
`int operator "" _b (const char * s) { .. }`

**userliteral.cpp**

```
...
int operator "" _b (const char * s, size_t l)
{
     int decimal {0};
     ...//conversion
     return decimal;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int bin2dez01 = "110011"_b;    //<--- string "110011" to const char *s, size_t l ??????
std::cout << bin2dez01 << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator ""` converts a string literal within the program source into another type, in this case an `int` based on parsing a string representation of a binary number.

The type of a string literal in C++ is `const char *` - a constant pointer to an array of `char` representing the contents of the string. You also get a `size_t` which tells you how long the string is, because you can't tell that just from the pointer.

(The standard for strings in C and C++ is to put a null byte `\0` to mark the end of the string, but finding that isn't free, and sometimes they get left out by mistake, so it's always easier to pass the pointer and the length around when you can).

The standard string class `std::string` can be constructed from a string literal, but unlike in languages like C# and Java they are absolutely not the same type. You get the illusion of it a lot because `std::string` has various conversion operators and overloads to allow you to work more or less seamlessly with string literals in the ways you'd expect to be able to.

So in summary, there's no conversion going on - the string literal really *is* a `const char *`, and the `size_t` tells you how long it is.

Comment: To be exact, the type of a string literal is **const char[N]** where N is the size of the string in code units of the execution narrow encoding, including the null terminator.
This is important, because it allows creation of a std::string using the size, i.e. without computing the length by looking for the null character.